# Calculating which quarters occur in a timeframe

Tags: r

My dataset has monthly reporting which needs to be summed to return both the quarterly value and the 12 month rolling rate. I have successfully created a column specifying which quarter each row is from by using `df$Quarter <- quarter(df$Month, fiscal_start = 4, with_year = T)`, this returns as `2022.1`etc which I then use as part of my `group_by` to sum all values in that quarter. I however now need to create a row for each area which returns the 4 quarter sum based upon when I update the dataset, which will be done quarterly.

If this were my data I would want it to end up something like the second table
|Area|Quarter|Measure_1|
|----|-------|---------|
|Area_a|2022.1|5|
|Area_a|2021.4|1|
|Area_a|2021.3|2|
|Area_a|2021.2|6|
|Area_b|2022.1|9|
|Area_b|2021.4|7|
|Area_b|2021.3|2|
|Area_b|2021.2|1|

It doesn't need to be exactly like this but this is the rough idea of what I want to happen

| Area | Quarter | Measure_1 | Timeframe |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Area_a | 2022.1 | 5 | Quarterly |
| Area_a | 2021.4 | 1 | Quarterly |
| Area_a | 2021.3 | 2 | Quarterly |
| Area_a | 2021.2 | 6 | Quarterly |
| Area_a | 2022.1 | 14 | 12 month rolling |
| Area_b | 2022.1 | 9 | Quarterly |
| Area_b | 2021.4 | 7 | Quarterly |
| Area_b | 2021.3 | 2 | Quarterly |
| Area_b | 2021.2 | 1 | Quarterly |
| Area_b | 2022.1 | 19 | 12 month rolling |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code produces the required results from your sample data. If your real data covers multiple years for each Area, then you would have to calculate a year variable and then include it along with `Area` in the `group_by()`.

```
want <- df %>% 
    group_by(Area) %>% 
    # use summarise to calculate totals
    # Quarter variable will be used to sort the output, new_Quarter will ensure
    #  that the total row has the maximum Quarter value for that area
    summarise(new_Quarter=max(Quarter), Quarter=min(Quarter)-0.05, Measure_1=sum(Measure_1)) %>% 
    bind_rows(df) %>% # combine the totals with the original data
    arrange(Area,-Quarter)%>% # sort so that total rows come after the quarters
    mutate(Quarter=if_else(is.na(new_Quarter),Quarter,new_Quarter), # assign maximum Quarter to total row
           Timeframe=if_else(is.na(new_Quarter),'Quarterly','12 month rolling')) %>% # add label
    select(-new_Quarter) # remove temporary variable
```